# Maybe to Completable

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I hava a `Maybe<>` source and some action that I want to execute with this value if maybe is not empty:

```
// Maybe<T> maybe();
// Completable action(T value);
return maybe().flatMapCompletable(val -> action(val));
```

but when maybe is empty I want to get 'completed' completable:

```
return Completable.complete();
```

How to make this switch: if maybe is not empty get one completable, otherwise another?

Comment: if the other completable is Completable.complete(), you don't need to do anything, in case the maybe will not emit anything (while not get onError)  you will simply get onComplete, is that what you want?

Comment: @yosriz yes, I want to return `Completable.complete()` when maybe is empty

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, I have written two tests, and I think this behaviour you want is given out of the box. The maybeTest will complete without calling saveToDb. maybeTest2 will call saveToDb and flatten the value back and complete.

```
@Test
public void maybeTest() throws Exception {
    Completable completable = Maybe.<Integer>empty()
            .flatMapCompletable(o -> {
                System.out.println(o);

                return saveToDb(5);
            });

    completable.test().await().assertComplete();
}


@Test
public void maybeTest2() throws Exception {
    Completable completable = Maybe.just(5)
            .flatMapCompletable(o -> {
                System.out.println(o);

                return saveToDb(5);
            });

    completable.test().await().assertComplete();
}

private Completable saveToDb(long value) {
    return Completable.complete();
}
```